# how to find what button is pressed

Tags: javascript, html

i am making a clicker game and need to find out which button is being clicked.
i am not sure how to do this.

this is my javascript

```
var multiplyer = 1
var carparts = 0;
document.getElementById("karpartz").innerHTML = carparts;
function onButtonClick() {
    carparts = carparts + multiplyer;
    document.getElementById("karpartz").innerHTML = carparts; 
}

const button = document.querySelector('button'); 
  button.addEventListener('click', onButtonClick);
```

and this is my html

```
<button type="submit">
  <img src= "example"
alt="buttonpng" border="0" />
</button>

<button>
  upgrade click power
</button>
<button>
  upgrade idle scrapping
</button>

<p id="karpartz"></p>

<html>

  <body>
    <h1>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write(karpartz)

      </script>
    </h1>
  </body>

</html>
```

how do i find which one is clicked

i also cant find how to get rid of [object HTMLParagraphElement]

Comment: Hi, you have to add an id to your buttons like so: `<button id="myid">...` (a different one for each, then in your function add an event parameter `function onButtonClick(event)` and then inside the function you can access `event.target.id` which will be the id of the pressed button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the event handler to each button then pass in some sort of identifier from the event.currenttarget (I'm using the text of your button). run code snippet below

```js
const onButtonClick = (buttonText) => 
  console.log(`you clicked the ${buttonText || 'submit'} button`);


const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button'); // Select all buttons

buttons.forEach(button => button.addEventListener(
  'click', event => onButtonClick(
    event.currentTarget.textContent.trim())));
```

```html
<button type="submit">
  <img src= "example"
alt="buttonpng" border="0" />
</button>

<button>
  upgrade click power
</button>
<button>
  upgrade idle scrapping
</button>
```